# Is it possible to nest forms two levels deep in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, rxjs

I need to nest a formgroup two levels deep for a functionality in an Angular project. This is the situation:

I have multiple small formgroups. These all have a common *parentform*.
For a new page I need one *seperate formgroup* and all the children of the *parentform*.
I'm trying to create a new **parentform** that has two children: the *seperate formgroup* and the first *parentform*.

I'm trying to do it this way to avoid too much duplicate code.
The structure I'm trying to end up with looks like this:

```
child formgroups \
                  ==> original parentform \
                                           ==> new parentform
                       seperate formgroup /
```

Currently I'm importing both the original *parentform* and the *seperate formgroup* in the same way. ie: parentform.AddControl('*seperate*', *seperate formgroup*);
parentform.AddControl('original parent', *parentform*);

The problem I'm running into is that the form itself is being updated but the object in the body of the PUT request is not.

Is it at all possible to use formgroup nesting more than one level deep?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is,

```
  form!: FormGroup;
  
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
     // incialize form structure
     this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      1: ['', Validators.required],
      2: this.formBuilder.group({
        2_1: ['', [Validators.required]],
        2_2:  ['', [Validators.required]],
      })
    });
  }

<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="1" />

    <div class="form-group" formGroupName="2">
      <input type="text" formControlName="2_1" />
      <input type="text" formControlName="2_2" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and so  on ...